# ［ターミネーター2］ How to pronouce Terminator 2 (name of the movie)

Tags: pronunciation

There is a famouse movie by James Cameron "Terminator 2"
In English it is pronounced "Terminator two".

In Wikipedia I found how the name of this movie is written in Japanese (katakana, of course)
［ターミネーター2］

But I do not know how Japanese pronounce it.

> ta:mine:ta: ni
>   ta:mine:ta: futa
>   ta:mine:ta: futatsu

Which one is correct?

or maybe deal is pretty crasy and the right answer is?

> ターミネーターチュ
>   ta:mine:ta: tyu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's タミネーター・ツー (ta:mine:ta: tsu:). For reference, the number in a work of fiction's title is generally always pronounced as an approximation of English.

ワン

ツー

スリー

フォー

ファイブ

シックス

セブン

エイト

ナイン

and so on.

Comment: I got your idea and was pretty shocked yesterday, but today I'm feeling better and have subquestion. What if there is no English title for the movie? What if there is only original Japanese title? For example, imagine that movie 人食い猫 is a huge hit and producers dicided to make 人食い猫2. How would Japanese pronounce that title? I doubt that it is [hito-gui neko - tsu].

Comment: @Tchibi-kun It would indeed be ひとぐいねこ・ツー (Hitogui Neko Tsuu).

Comment: Oh, my God!! After your answer for me it is "I am Shocked. Day 2". Anyway, the deeper I study Japanese language, the more I understand, that when they say, that Japan is like a country from other planet, the more I feel, that is not just a rumor. Indeed. Japanese are very different! But I like it and I feel motivated to go on studying, no matter what other suprises are awaiting me in future.

Comment: 「人食い猫」は「ひと**ぐ**いねこ」じゃなくて「ひと**く**いねこ」って読みます

Comment: This is a great question also in a sense which you did not think of i.e. why the last ー. Many words like manager, elevator etc are OK both with or without, ie エレベータ is OK, but at least tower always has it (ie you don't write タワ but it has to be タワー). I was thinking if it could be since the tower does not "tow" (although I don't know the ethymology of this ENglish word), but I think that also dealer also required  the ー ie you would not say ディーラ

Comment: @Chocolate そうでしたね、ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1):

In many loan words with a number, the number is pronounced in the original language word mapped to katakana, so "2" here is pronounced as ツー (tsu:). Same applies to e.g PlayStation: プレイステーションツー, プレイステーションスリー, プレイステーションフォー